# New browser tabs for pdf files from glob-created list?

Tags: php, html

To list a large number of sheet-music pdfs on a website, I'm using this at the top of my php/html file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function getFiles(){
    $files=array();
    if($dir=opendir('.')){
        while($file=readdir($dir)) {
            if($file!='.' && $file!='..'){
                $files[]=($file);
            }   
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }
    natsort($files); //sort
    return $files;
}
?>
```

... then in the ul bit of the html section I have this:

```
 <? foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $file)
    echo "<li name=\"".$file."\"><a href=\"".$file."\">$file</a></li>";
    ?>
```

It works fine, except that when clicked, the pdf replaces the web page content in the browser, and I would prefer it to appear in a separate browser tab.
I've tried inserting "_blank" in various places but it kills the page, so I'm obviously not doing it right (I'm a musician, not a programmer!). 
Similar questions on here seem to relate to different set-ups and I don't have the knowledge to apply the answers to my situation. 
How can I get my otherwise successful website set-up to trigger a new browser tab for each tune clicked?  Thanks.

Comment: *"I've tried inserting "_blank" in various places"* -- the correct place is in the `a` element: `<a href="..." target="_blank"...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"I've tried inserting "_blank" in various places"* -- the correct place is in the `a` element: `<a href="..." target="_blank"...>`

The code of your template should read:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.pdf") as $file) {
    echo '<li name="'.$file.'"><a href="'.$file.'" target="_blank">'.$file.'</a></li>';
}
?>
```